# New Github Desktop can't use external repositories

Tags: git, github, bitbucket, github-desktop

I updated to a new github desktop (native app): https://desktop.github.com/

With old client i can manage my external bitbucket repositories but i dont know how can i do with the new application.

When i try to synchronize i recieve an auth error:

[image]

Any idea?

Comment: Anyone can help me?

Comment: I'm also trying to manage a private BitBucket repository using latest GitHub Desktop and it doesn't work.
If i run "git pull" from Mac Terminal it works perfectly (i've inserted my Mac public ssh key id_rsa.pub in BitBucket ssh keys panel).
But if i try to pull or push thru GitHub Desktop it doesn't seem to be using the keys.
I've also tried to add bitbucket.org host to "config" file, nothing changed:
#Bitbucket
  Host bitbucket.org
  HostName bitbucket.org
  User bitbucketUserName
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
Any updates to this ?